# Add additonal class names to custom React component

Tags: css, reactjs, components, custom-component

I'm wondering how to add additional class name to a custom React component, like a Button. So far I've tried with a traditional way of using `class1 ${class2}` and even `classnames` but it's not successful.

Here's my sample to my attempt: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/1zp7m2yv3

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import classNames from "classnames";
import "./styles.css";

const ButtonTest = props => {
  // const className = `button is-testing is-gradient ${props.className ? props.className : ''}`;
  const className = classNames(
    "button is-testing is-gradient cv",
    props.className
  );
  console.log("a:", className);

  if (props.href) {
    return (
      <a href={props.href} className={className} {...props}>
        {props.children}
      </a>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button className={className} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ButtonTest href="https://google.vn">BUTTON LINK</ButtonTest>
      <ButtonTest className="aaa is-block">DEFAULT</ButtonTest>
      <ButtonTest href="https://google.vn" className="is-block dfdfdf">
        BUTTON LINk - FULL
      </ButtonTest>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Thanks,
D

Comment: Can you please describe your issue indetail?

Comment: the issue is when I try to add more classes, it seems like the defined classes ```button is-testing is-gradient cv``` is replaced by newer ones, the expected result in my sample is all the Button component should have a border around, because of the ```.is-testing``` in CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because you are spreading the `props` after giving the `className` attribute to your components.

So `<ButtonTest className="aaa is-block">DEFAULT</ButtonTest>` will try to render

```
<button className={className} {...props}>
```

which expands to

```
<button className={className} className={"aaa is-block"}>
```

and the last same-named attribute is what prevails.

You can invert the order and use

```
<button {...props} className={className} >
```

so that the spread `props` will be overridden by any custom props you pass.

See https://codesandbox.io/s/oqvy6qp56z

---

Or you could extract the props you want to directly use so that the `props` only holds the rest

Like

```
const ButtonTest = ({className:passedClasses, ...props}) => {
  const className = classNames(
    "button is-testing is-gradient cv",
    passedClasses
  );
  console.log("a:", className);

  if (props.href) {
    return (
      <a href={props.href} className={className} {...props}>
        {props.children}
      </a>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button className={className} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/l7ro16wqz9

Comment: thanks for your quick and clear explanation, shame on me for didn't notice the order I put my the ```...props``` in the first place.

The second suggestion is something new to me, and will give it a try. Big thanks to you